# How do I change the content of a react native drawer like on a regular screen?

Tags: react-native, jsx, react-native-ios

Suppose you have a drawer navigator created through

```
const GalioApp = createDrawerNavigator(screens, options);
```

How can I change the drawer content like in a regular screen? For example change what's written on top to something else, or change a navigator button content for example to change the language of it

Answer (score 0):

You can create custom drawer component and set `drawerWidth` to width of the screen which will open drawer in fullscreen width. Then you can render your custom view on drawer with `contentComponent` prop of drawer navigator. For example :

```js
import { Dimensions } from 'react-native';
const { width } = Dimensions.get('screen');

const CustomFullScreenDrawer = (props) => {
  return (
    // make your custom view here
  )
}

const GalioApp = createDrawerNavigator(screens, {
  drawerWidth: width,
  contentComponent: (props) => <CustomFullScreenDrawer {...props} />
});
```

[Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/drawer-navigator#contentoptions-for-draweritems) is the full list of props which helps you to create better custom drawer.

Comment: I am not sure that's what I had in mind. Let me express it differently. I want something like a setState like you have for the screens but for the drawer. Something like the user name that changes in the drawer after the user logs in. How to I make it change without restarting the app?